# Querying MySQL table with Idiorm/Paris

Tags: php, idiorm

I've a `Paris` based model with its relative 'posts' table:

```
class Post extends Model { 
    public static $_table = 'posts';
    public static $_id_column = 'id';
}
```

When I make a simple query to grab all posts:

```
$posts = Model::factory('Post')->find_many();
var_dump($posts);
```

this is what I get in response:

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  object(Post)#34 (1) {
    ["orm"]=>
    object(ORM)#21 (19) {
      ["_table_name":protected]=>
      string(5) "posts"
      ["_table_alias":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_values":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_result_columns":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
      ["_using_default_result_columns":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["_join_sources":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_distinct":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_is_raw_query":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_raw_query":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["_raw_parameters":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_where_conditions":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_limit":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_offset":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_order_by":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_group_by":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_data":protected]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "Primo post"
        ["content"]=>
        string(11) "prova prova"
        ["published"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["_dirty_fields":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_is_new":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_instance_id_column":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
    }
  }
  etc...
```

Now the question is: How do I access the datas? Because I cannot access that. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Original Answer

You can do this in the following way:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
}
```

As you can see I am first looping over the records and then printing the title of each one. Everthing in the protected data property of your result can be accessed in this way:

```
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "Primo post"
    ["content"]=>
    string(11) "prova prova"
    ["published"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

So you could get the content by calling:

```
echo $post->content;
```

As an aside the guy who wrote Paris and Idiorm, Jamie, used to work with me so let me know if you have any other questions.

### Answer to question in the comments

You can encode it to JSON in the following way:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo json_encode($post->as_array());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However I'm not able to encode the results in JSON.

Comment: @S.C. I have updated my answer to address that. You can use the `as_array()` method.

Answer (score 8):

More on encoding a Paris model as JSON. This will return all `_data` in the array as a JSON string:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function ($post) {
    return $post->as_array();
}, $posts))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect for me, I really wish this was part of Paris/Idiorm, I would fork and add it in if I were more familiar with those.  

Maybe someone has done this already?
Found it: https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/issues/17
Going to give that a try

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the latest version of paris and idiorm, you can use **find_array()**

```
$posts = Model::factory('Post')->find_array();
```

Thanks to Tim W. for inspiring me to pursue this.

[GitHub: Multiple Results as Array Issue](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/issues/17)

[Documentation - As an associative array](https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html?highlight=select_many_expr#as-an-associative-array)